# Python trigger __new__ without __init__?

Tags: python, constructor, init

I have a class A:

```
class A:
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(a1, a2)
```

Now I'd like to pass in a new argument `a3` to create factory

```
class A:
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs):
       # Do sth with a3

    def __init__(a1, a2)
```

So here `a3` is only used in `__new__`, but I realized I must pass in `a3` into `__init__` first to get it work, so that I need to modify `__init__` into `def __init__(a1, a2, a3)` or `def __init__(a1, a2, **kwargs)`. It's weird that I pass `a3` but never use it in `__init__`

So basically here is there anyway I could just trigger `__new__` without changing `__init__`?

Comment: Why are you using both `__new__` and `__init__`? Things go smoothest if you stick with one or the other.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/why-is-init-always-called-after-new) recommends that you use a factory function *instead* of `__new__`. It shouldn't be the way to implement the factory.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468112/python-override-init-args-in-new

Comment: Post an actual [mcve] please. I am having a bit of trouble following your made-up pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__new__` and `__init__` are called by `type.__call__`. Normally, when `__new__` returns an instance of the target class, the metaclass calls `__init__` on the result. You can override this behavior by changing the metaclass:

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # you can omit `__init__` entirely, or you can replicate
        # what `type` does, but strip the last positional argument:
        if isinstance(obj, cls):
            if len(args) > 2:
                args = args[:2]
            cls.__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj

class A(metaclass=MetaA):
    ...
```